# pyenv installed version opening idle in black screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle, pyenv

I'm a MacOS user, I have installed latest MacOs Mojave on the system.
I have installed Python 3.7.2 which is currently the latest version, after that, I come to know that the latest version doesn't support tensorflow.

so what I did, I install pyenv version 1.2.8 to create different installations of python. with pyenv I installed 3.6.7 and now tensorflow is working fine by using "pyenv global 3.6.7", but when I try to load idle using "python -m idlelib" it opens the idle but screen is totally black I can't see anything I can't write anything.

If you have any further question or you don't understand what is my problem, kindly do let me know.

I am using Dark Mode of Mojave, but Normal or Dark Mode of Mojave doesn't make any difference

Comment: Are you using Dark Mode on Mojave? 1) Pyenv isn't making things black 2) that's not your only option for python development

Comment: Yes, I'm using Dark Mode of Mojave, but 3.7.2 is working fine in this mode only the version installed with pyenv which is 3.6.7 have issue opening idle

Comment: also if i import turtle module even that is not showing up with 3.6.7 but with 3.7.2 installed with installer, it's working fine.

Comment: Have you tried searching through the Python or IDLE changelog regarding this issue? My point is that Mojave was probably released after Python 3.6.7, and so nobody knew IDLE would become a black screen

Comment: I googled a lot about the issue but I can't figure it out so that is why I posted here, I'm using Mac from last 4 years but I'm learning python from the last 1 month. Normal or Dark Mode of Mojave doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend Pycharm or Sypder IDEs (or Jupyter notebooks). I'm not particularly sure why IDLE would be black

Comment: I'm using VSCode and everything works fine except IDLE and Turtle Graphics as it loads wish(tcl/tk) and stuck there.

Comment: Vscode can run Python with an extension. Not sure I understand why you'd use IDLE, then

Comment: anyhow I installed 3.6.7 just for tensorflow and that is working, but I was curious why IDLE and Turtle Graphics not working that is why I posted here, so might someone have a solution for this.

Comment: furthermore, if I remove 3.7.2 and install 3.6.7 normally with the .pkg file then it also works the only problem is when I'm trying to use pyenv, so I'm sure it has to do something with pyenv environment. so python 3.6.7 is working if I install it via .pkg installer

Comment: I'm fairly sure pyenv downloads a tar.gz directly from the Python website... You could try miniconda2 or pypy as alternatives

Comment: Ok I will give a short to pypy and miniconda2 packages as well and yes pyenv grab packages from original python website in tar.gz format.

Comment: The underlying problem is getting tcl/tk to simultaneously run on different versions of macOS under different conditions.  Tkinter and hence IDLE are victims of this problem. Mohave changed something in its graphics system such that tcl/tk had be be changed to avoid regressions on Mohave, but those changes introduced regressions in older version, so we could not use the latest fixes in 3.7.2 and 3.6.8.  See https://bugs.python.org/issue34313.  You might do better with 3.6.8 in your venv.  I don't remember an issue about opening with black screen, so you might open a new issue.